# Simple RestFul WebService with Component-scan

Tags: java, spring, rest, jax-rs

I am trying to autowire an object using component-scan in my restFul Webservice. But getting Nullpointer exception when **userDao** object is used.

I dont want to use Spring MVC or spring boot. Just want to simply inject the dependency using component-scan. Please help!!!

**UserDao.java**

```
@Component
public class UserDao { 
public List<User> getAllUsers(){ 
    //return a list 
} 
}
```

**UserService.java**

```
@Component
@Path("/UserService") 
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        System.out.println("userDao object: " + userDao);
    }

    @GET 
    @Path("/users") 
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
    public List<User> getUsers(){ 
        return getUserDao().getAllUsers(); 
    }  

    public UserDao getUserDao() {
        return userDao;
    }

    public void setUserDao(UserDao userDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }
}
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:aop = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd ">

   <context:annotation-config/>
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.rest"/>
   <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
   xmlns = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"  
   id = "WebApp_ID" version = "3.0"> 
   <display-name>User Management</display-name> 
   <servlet> 
      <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name> 
      <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class> 
      <init-param> 
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name> 
         <param-value>com.rest</param-value> 
      </init-param> 
      <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>      
   </servlet> 
   <servlet-mapping> 
      <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name> 
      <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern> 
   </servlet-mapping> 

</web-app>
```

Comment: My Restful webservice is working fine without spring. Now I need to configure Spring and inject the dependencies.

Comment: Then this might be the [closer option](http://www.baeldung.com/jersey-rest-api-with-spring), if you dont want to configure a Spring Context

Comment: Look at the [official example project](https://github.com/jersey/jersey-1.x/tree/master/samples/spring-annotations)

Comment: what is the name of package in which UserDAO resides?

Comment: all the classes resides in com.rest package

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define a bean in your applicationContext.xml file. Spring container initializes this bean when the application is started. 
eg.

```
<bean id="userDAO" class="your.package.name.UserDAO">
<!-- In case if you use hibernate -->
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

As an analogy, you can think of this as spring is doing `UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO();` for you.

Comment: But if I need to use component-scan. Then what should be the procedure?